# C++ For Loop. Int. values are not being summed correctly

Tags: c++

Beginner here. So I'm trying to get this code to print the total value for each year. I've entered 10 for every value and for year 3 it returns 126 while I expect 120. The other two years return the correct value 120. I'm having trouble figuring out why this isn't working as intended.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    const int Years = 3;
    const int Months = 12;
    int booksales[Years][Months];
    int total[3];
    for (int year = 0; year < Years; ++year)
    {
        int yr_total = 0;
        for (int month = 0; month < Months; ++month)
        {
            cout << "Enter book sales for year " << (year + 1)
            << " month " << (month + 1) << ": ";
            cin >> booksales[year][month];
            total[year] += booksales[year][month];
        }
     }
cout << "TOTAL for year 1: " << total[0] << endl;
cout << "TOTAL for year 2: " << total[1] << endl;
cout << "TOTAL for year 3: " << total[2] << endl;
cout << "OVERALL TOTAL: " << total[0] + total[1] + total[2] << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did not initialize array

```
int total[3];
```

Thus in this statement

```
total[year] += booksales[year][month];
```

the behavior is undefined.

Write

```
int total[3] = {};
```

Also this declaration inside the outer loop

```
int yr_total = 0;
```

is redundant. The variable is not used.

Comment: Interesting. I had wrongly assumed if I declared the array I'd be able to add values into it using the for loop. But I guess until it's initialized you can't do that. Thank you!

Comment: @Sabazios: You _can_ add values to it, but you don't know what its original "value" is so you also don't know what your result will be. Though technically the whole thing has UB, so...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Makes sense. I understand now that it is null and therefore produces an unpredictable outcome, though I am a little surprised it wouldn't just set the values equal to zero by default and then overwrite them if specified.

Comment: @Sabazios: No, it is not "null"; it is unspecified. The reason it's not zero, though, is because there is a runtime cost for setting something to zero (or to any value), and in C++ you do not pay for what you don't use. You can zero-initialise it yourself if you want (as Vlad demonstrated), but if you do not need it to be zero-initialised then the language will not do it for you, so that you do not pay the cost regardless.

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not initialize variables to known values.  In this case you are summing your yearly totals into an array of uninitialized data (`total`).  The surprise is that years 1 and 2 don't show a similar problem.

It looks like you attempted to clear this data with the variable `yr_total` instead of the arrays total.  Try replacing the first line of your year loop with the following: `total[year] = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with your code is the initialization part.

Ideally, you should initialise the total array instead of leaving it with garbage value.

```
int total[3] = {};
```

Hope it helps.